# How to make a method taking any case class as a argument and use it as type

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm using play framework and its JSON parser play.api.libs.json and I have some case class for doing JSON parse.
I'd like to validate if a request json is valid or invalid so I would like to add `isValidJson` method to my trait which all json request's case class extends but I do not know how to call case class as `Type` from the trait.

here is my question, how can I turn into a method taking json and any case class as arguments and return a validation result if the json matches to the case class or not from the code below?

```
val isValidRequest = {
  request.body.validate[CaseClassOfSomething](Json.format[CaseClassOfSomething]).map {
    case x:CaseClassOfSomething =>
      true
  }.recoverTotal{
    case e => false
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def isValidRequest[T: Reads](implicit request: Request[JsValue]) =
  request.body.asOpt[T].isDefined
```

Then you can use it as `isValidRequest[Foo]` which will return true if the Reader for `Foo` can read the json from the request body correctly. Also note that this is compile safe, i.e if you write `isValidRequest[Bar]` and you don't have a `Reads[Bar]` defined in scope then it won't compile.

Although to be frank it's probably just better to inline this in your controllers if you're just aiming to hit back with `Bad Request`. i.e:

```
def get() = Action { implicit request =>
  request.body.asOpt[Foo].map(
    doSomething(_)
      .map(Ok("Great!")
  .getOrElse(BadRequest)
}
```